# I get "Parsing errors" on .ts files when I migrate my app from React 16.x to 17.x

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I am working to migrate a React app to the latest v17.x version (from 16.13.0).

However I am getting parsing errors on the typescript files when I upgrade React (the app uses javascript mostly, but some files were later added in typescript).

e.g.

```
src\components\data\Assets\FYAsset.ts
  Line 2:11:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  1 | export class FYAsset {
> 2 |   private apiData: Object | undefined; // the res data, as received from the API
    |           ^
  3 |
  4 |   private id: number | undefined;
  5 |   private providerId: number | undefined;

src\components\data\Users\FYUser.ts
  Line 5:19:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  3 |
  4 | export class FYUserConstants {
> 5 |   static readonly USERGROUPID_ADMIN = 1;
    |                   ^
  6 |   static readonly USERGROUPLABEL_ADMIN = "ADMIN";
  7 |   //
  8 |   static readonly USERGROUPID_EXPERT = 2;
```

The old app uses the following versions (which work fine):
react-scripts v3.4.0
react/react-dom v16.13.0
typescript v3.8.3

For the migration, the errors appear when I move over to react-scripts v4.0.1 and react v17.0.1. I tried upgrading typescript to v4.1.3 but that didn't change anything.

Again, everything works fine in the previous branch. Could you suspect what causes the issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by deleting the **.eslintcache** file that was carried over from the legacy project.